# How to chat with a specific online user by getting its ConnectionId in asp.net SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

1> I am also using IUserIdProvider, in that I have problem of 'How should I get the connectionId of the specific online User to whom I want to send a message?'

2> I have also tried for displaying online users count on a page and its working but it not showing Context.User.identity.Name.

3> I also tried by using events Listerner.

***But still I didn't know that how to get a ConnectionId of a online user and send a message to him ??? Thats the big headache problem for me please help me..

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anonymous authentication on your web server? If so, you won't see the user's name.

Comment: ohh..yeah...i was not authenticate the user so that this problem was created..thanks